# no bootable device can be found after switching to legacy mode

Tags: boot, multi-boot

The reason that i want to switch to Legacy mode is that i need to use easyBCD.(i am trying to dual boot kali linux and win10)
However, it seems that my Win10 is not detected in the legacy mode.
is it because that my win10 is just for EFI? And how can i solve this problem?
Thanks a lot.
[partition wizard info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMOV8.png)
[BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxXRA.jpg)
[BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxwul.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you install Windows with EFI enabled and then switch to Legacy BIOS, the system will not find any bootable device. Switch back to EUFI and you should be able to bootup Windows 10.

If you really want to keep BIOS to Legacy, then you will have to format the PC and install Windows 10 again. Windows 10 supports installation on machines with Legacy BIOS and EUFI.

Comment: Hi, but i have disabled UEFI and enabled legacy mode while i was installing kali linunx. However, it still can't find any bootable device either. Do u know what i should do to solve it?

Comment: Did you install Kali Linux or did you just run its Live CD? You can try booting with Kali CD again and check if its installed.

Comment: yes i have checked that it was installed. i followed the steps shown in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLj2yQPWZDk&t=539s

Comment: is it because that my partition style is GPT? and it cannot be recognised by legacy mode?

Comment: Could be. Eaiest way is to completely format the drive and re-install Windows and then Kali. Note that next time Windows upgrades, it will remove GRUB